# Exception while trying to decrypt in PDFBox

Tags: java, exception, encryption, spring-boot, pdfbox

While trying to decrypt an encrypted PDF using PDFBox, I am facing an exception -

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfmodel.encryption.StandardSecurityHandler.computeEncryptedKey
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfmodel.encryption.StandardSecurityHandler.computeUserPassword
```

The code I am using is

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
if (doc.isEncrypted()) {
   StandardDecryptionMaterial dm = new StandardDecryptionMaterial(password);
   doc.openProtection(dm);
}
```

The exception happens at openProtection method.
I also tried doc.decrypt method, but with the same result.

My maven contains

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
  <version>1.44</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15</artifactId>
  <version>1.44</version>
</dependency>
```

Java version is 1.7

I tried multiple version of PDFBox/bouncyCastle (1.8.7/1.46) - but still this exception persists.

If I try qpdf --decrypt to decrypt the file before hand and it is working perfectly. But when I try to decrypt using code, it fails with the previous exception.

I am using this inside a Spring Boot application - Can that be a reason?

If anyone can point me to a possible solution, I would be much obliged.

Comment: are you using "owner password"?

Comment: Please share the PDF. Also try with 2.0.7 with newer BC version (pass the password in PDDocument.load()). If you insist on using 1.8.13, then use loadNonSeq() (and pass the password there, do not call openProtection)

Comment: Thank you Tilman Hausherr. It worked - I am also adding the same as an answer - for use for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Tilman Hausherr.

I tried PDFBox 2.0.7 and it worked perfectly.